# header Content-Type: application/json returning text/html

Tags: php, json, apache, header

I have the following code that is supposed to output in the content-type: json.

```
public static function getTest()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $result = ['foo' => 'bar'];
    $json = json_encode($result);

    echo $json;
}
```

On my production server (godaddy shared hosting - Apache 2.4.10 & PHP 5.4.31) the response type comes back: application/json.  However on my local WAMP server (Apache 2.4.9 & PHP 5.5.12) the response type is 'text/html' (as seen in Firebug).  This is causing me problems as I develop a series of API's that need to be json.  My first guess was an apache mime type issue but that has not panned out for me.

Any ideas?  I am sorry if this is perhaps more of a server config issue.  But I am baffled and thought it possible that I missed something in my PHP.ini or even my code.

All help gratefully received.  Thanks!

EDIT - I have fiddled with it a bit and learned something else.  If I change the 'Content-type' to application/xml, my production server spits out the expected error reflecting the improperly formatted content for the xml standard.  However, my local WAMP server still uses a response header with a content-type of text/html.  Is there a setting to override header assignments in Apache or in PHP?

Comment: Check your error log. Do you see any entries saying something like “headers already sent”?

Comment: Nothing.  I set my logging level down to debug and restarted my local service... but nothing more than 'child thread blahblah... listening on...'  Are you thinking that something was getting echo'd out before the header command?  That was my first thought.

Comment: That’s what I thought might be happening, but if it’s not in the error log, the problem could be elsewhere. I’m not sure where next to look, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why my two servers are behaving differently with the header command.  But the good news is that I am doing this within Laravel and I found a solution there.  This works beautifully for me:

```
    public static function getTest()
    {
        $result = ['foo' => 'bar'];

        return Response::json($result);
    }
```